# Business intelligence - Can't find the value I'm looking for

Tags: sql, ssas, business-intelligence

I'm setting up a SSAS project for our websites but I can't managed to find the good value whereas it's quite simple in plain SQL query.

Here's my setup : I have a datawarehouse filled with user connection fact on my sites. And so I have a Member dimension and a date dimension. Heres's the KPI I'm loking for : "For how many average days a user is coming to see our site".

Let's take an example :

```
Member    Day
a         1
a         1
a         2
b         2
a         4
a         5
b         5
a         6
```

In this case the KPI should give 3,5 (a=5, b=2). In plain SQL I would have done an average on a group by on a group by (it's the first request I've got in mind, maybe there's a better one).

But as soon as I try to assemble dimension and facts together I can't find the right measure.

Am I looking for the wrong thing ? Should I abandon my SQL way of thinking ? How would you do to get the value I need ?

Comment: You you explain how you get this? `In this case the KPI should give 3,5 (a=5, b=2).`

Comment: Yes, in words, the user a is coming on day 1 (twice), 2, 4, 5 and 6. That is 5 days (and 6 visits). User b is coming on day 2 and 5 which makes 2 days (and 2 visits).

So the average number of days a user is coming on my applications is (5 + 2) / 2.

In SQL I would have done 

    SELECT AVG(Visits) FROM(SELECT Member, COUNT(*) Visits FROM (SELECT Member, COUNT(*) VisitPerDay FROM Connection GROUP BY Member, Day) t1 GROUP BY t1.MemberId) t2

(Sorry for the bad formatting, i don't know how to do it in comments)

Comment: You can put ` around your code to get the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now!  It was just an internationalisation problem.  To me `3,5` means the numbers `3` and `5`, I'd write it as `3.5` :)

```
SELECT
  AVG(CountOfDay) As AverageDays
FROM
  (SELECT Member, COUNT(DISTINCT Day) CountOfDay FROM YourTable GROUP BY Member) AS UniqueDaysByMember
```

Really you don't need "Member" in the sub-query's SELECT.  It just makes it "mean" something to me, so I don't get confused if I come back and look at the code later!

Comment: Ok that's clearer now. That's the infamous COUNT DISTINCT. But that does not answer my question about how can I get this result in SSAS. In now how to set a COUNT DISTINCT measure, but how can I do an AVG on it ?